# Compare prices with php variables by script

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare prices in php file with variables but variables are calling by script:

```
<?php
$com1 = '<script language="javascript" src="https://www.lusoaloja.pt/cliente/feeds/domainprice.php?tld=.com&type=register&regperiod=1"></script>';
$com2 = '<script language="javascript" src="https://www.lusoaloja.pt/cliente/feeds/domainprice.php?tld=.com&type=renew&regperiod=1"></script>';
?>

<?php
if ($com1 == $com2) {
    echo 'equal prices';
} else {
    echo  "different prices" ;
}
?>

    <br>

<?php
$biz1 = '<script language="javascript" src="https://www.lusoaloja.pt/cliente/feeds/domainprice.php?tld=.biz&type=register&regperiod=1"></script>';
$biz2 = '<script language="javascript" src="https://www.lusoaloja.pt/cliente/feeds/domainprice.php?tld=.biz&type=renew&regperiod=1"></script>';
?>
<?php
if ($biz1 == $biz2) {
    echo "equal prices" ;
} else {
    echo  "different prices" ;
}
?>
```

I want that these 2 variables ($com1 and $com2 / $biz1 and $biz2) compare output prices, in this case the price in $com1 and $com2 are equal (8.50) and in $biz1 and $biz2 are different (9.70 and 5.00) but the result in two codes are "different prices"

If you do:

```
variable com1 = <?php echo $com1 ?><br>
variable com2 = <?php echo $com2 ?><br><br>

variable biz1 = <?php echo $biz1 ?><br>
variable biz2 = <?php echo $biz2 ?>
```

You can see that com1 and com2 are equal and biz1 and biz2 are different..
Anybody can help ?

Comment: use typecasting in if conditions: if ((float)$com1 == (float)$com2)

Answer (score 0):

Typecast $com1 and $com2 to float, so that it will convert both in float and then compare:

```
<?php
if ((float)$com1 == (float)$com2) {
    echo 'equal prices';
} else {
    echo  "different prices" ;
}
?>
```

Comment: It don't work too, the result in two are "equal prices" and have to be one equal and other different because in the first prices are equal and in the second prices are different :\